# Ember Integration test simulate transition to another route and then back

Tags: ember.js, integration-testing

Let me explain the issue first:
We have an Ember based dirty form checker that should reset the isDirty flag if the user transitions to another page and confirms the transition when there are changes on the page. We had a bug where, if the user transitioned with changes, confirmed the change, then returned, made no changes and navigated away again, the confirmation dialog appeared again. Simple fix, just reset the flag on the initial confirmation. Now, I'm trying to write an integration test for that, but I can find no clear documentation on how to test this. What I would like to do is programmatically alter the form, transition away, then back, then away again. How can I accomplish this? This is Ember 2.3.0.

Here's something I've tried:

```
 this.render(hbs `{{#mycomp invokeDialog=invokeDialog on-dirty=formDirtyEvent on-confirm=dialogConfirmEvent on-cancel=dialogCancelEvent}}
                    {{mytextfield id=id label="dummy-form-fullName"  type="text" inputBindValue="Paul Ryan"}}
                    {{/mycomp}}`);

            Ember.$("#textfield-" + this.get('id')).val("Paul Ryana");
            fillIn(Ember.$('#textfield-' + this.get('id')), 'Paul Ryanna');


            visit("/").then(function() {

             });
```

This generates the **error**:

> "Error: Assertion Failed: You cannot use the same root element
>   (#ember-testing) multiple times in an Ember.Application"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be using [acceptance tests](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.6.0/testing/acceptance/) for transitioning between routes. Integration tests ([component tests](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.6.0/testing/testing-components/)) are used just to test component functionality independently of the application flow. So you are getting that error because there are actually no routes for you to visit.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that.